# Error connecting to database when using mockgoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

The tests run well when using the real database, but after I mocked it with mockgoose, it reports an error

> Uncaught Error: Error connecting to database: failed to connect to [yankiserver-test:27017]
>         at null. 
>   (/Users/twer/GDrive/2Dev/node/yankiServer/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:555:74)
>         at emit (events.js:118:17)
>   ...

My project is based on MEAN.JS. I have added the mocking part to test.js.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mockgoose = require('mockgoose');
console.log('mocking goose');
mockgoose(mongoose);
```

It works well for saving model directly:

```
it('should be able to save without problems', function(done) {
    return article.save(function(err) {
        should.not.exist(err);
        done();
    });
});
```

But when I try to hit database through express

```
it('should be able to get a list of articles', function(done) {
  request(app).get('/articles/')
    .end(function(req, res) {
        done();
    });
});
```

It throws the above error.

Note: The connection has been established before running the test based on my debuging.

Comment: Mockgoose doesn't connect to mongodb that's why you don't get any error. Thats what mockgoose is for, it allows you to test mongoose models without the need to run mongodb.

Comment: Maybe mockgoose is somehow affecting the connection to DB you have in express

Comment: @Molda yes, I think so but need to know in which way so that I can change my test to use it properly.

Comment: Can't you separate the code into 2 files? One using mockgoose and another using real db.